# Function to burn NFT by taking contract address and token id as input args

Tags: contract-development, nft, burn

I want to create a "Burn" function in my contract which takes in NFT contract address and token id as input. The function will be called by the NFT owner to burn. Can someone explain how can I do this? If there are any relevant docs kindly mention the links

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to (assuming the NFT is burnable) :

1 - request allowance from the user for the NFT they're trying to burn (this is done on the frontend)

2 - Have your user call your contracts function that would :

```
-  TransferFrom() the NFT from the users wallet to the contract address.
-  Burn the NFT from the contract by calling its burn function. 
(alternatively, if the NFT isnt burnable, you can transfer it to an address no one has the private key for, such as address(0xdead)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, How can I request allowance from the user and How do I figure out whether a NFT is burnable or not? Please explain..

Comment: @Lobo1897 the user needs to call the [`approve`](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) function on the NFT to give your contract permission to take it from them. Some NFTs have a burn function which is non-standard. If there's no burn function, transferring it to a dummy address accomplishes the same goal. Or just transfer it to the contract, and make it so the contract doesn't have a way to give it away again

Comment: @user253751 How can I check whether a NFT has a burn function or not..?

Comment: @Lobo1897 go look at the code and see if there is one

Comment: @Lobo1897 im afraid theres no way you can do that from the EVM directly, so you'd either have to determine that on the frontend (by getting the NFT contracts Aabi (if  its public) and looking for a burn function, or you could also as user253751 just  keep the NFT in your contract and consider it burned